# NSFetchedResultsController not loading all entires

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a simple application with a `UITabBarController` and 2 `UITableViewControllers` in each `UITabBar`. The first `UITableViewController` is called `Videos` and the second is called `Languages`.

`Videos` will represent just the languages that have videos and Languages will display all of the languages.

For test purposes, I am populating the Core Data Entities from the AppDelegate.

My Core Data model is below:

[image]

The method that's populating the Core Data looks like this:

```
- (void)loadVideosTab
{
    // Here is where we'll load up the Videos tab.
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSString *chinese = @"Chinese";
    NSString *dutch = @"Dutch";
    NSString *english = @"English";
    NSString *french = @"French";
    NSString *italian = @"Italian";
    NSString *punjabi = @"Punjabi";
    NSString *spanish = @"Spanish";
    NSString *tamil = @"Tamil - தமிழ்";

    Language *language = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Language" inManagedObjectContext:context];


    Video *chineseLanguage = (Video *)[Video videoLanguage:chinese inManagedObjectContext:context];
    language.videos = chineseLanguage;
    Video *dutchLanguage = (Video *)[Video videoLanguage:dutch inManagedObjectContext:context];
    language.videos = dutchLanguage;
    Video *englishLanguage = (Video *)[Video videoLanguage:english inManagedObjectContext:context];
    language.videos = englishLanguage;
    Video *frenchLanguage = (Video *)[Video videoLanguage:french inManagedObjectContext:context];
    language.videos = frenchLanguage;
    Video *italianLanguage = (Video *)[Video videoLanguage:italian inManagedObjectContext:context];
    language.videos = italianLanguage;
    Video *punjabiLanguage = (Video *)[Video videoLanguage:punjabi inManagedObjectContext:context];
    language.videos = punjabiLanguage;
    Video *spanishLanguage = (Video *)[Video videoLanguage:spanish inManagedObjectContext:context];
    language.videos = spanishLanguage;
    Video *tamilLanguage = (Video *)[Video videoLanguage:tamil inManagedObjectContext:context];
    language.videos = tamilLanguage;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        // Error
    }    
}
```

The category I'm calling on the `Video` Entity is:

```
+ (Video *)videoLanguage:(NSString *)name inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Video *video = nil;

    // Creating a fetch request to check whether the video already exists, calling from the AppDelegate
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Video"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"language = %@", name];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"language" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *videoTitles = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!videoTitles)
    {
        // Handle Error
    }
    else if (![videoTitles count])
    {
        // If the video count is 0 then create it
        video = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Video" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        video.language = name;

    }
    else
    {
        // If the object exists, just return it
        video = [videoTitles lastObject];
    }
    return video;

}
```

So in the `Video` tab, I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` as so:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Video" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    fetchRequest.entity = entity;
    NSPredicate *d = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"language != nil"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:d];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"language" ascending:YES];


    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

And the `cellForRow` is:

```
VideoTabTableViewCell *customCell = (VideoTabTableViewCell *)cell;

Video *video = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

customCell.videoTabCellLabel.text = video.language;
customCell.videoTabCellLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

That successfully pulls in the languages.

Now, for test purposes, I want the Languages tab to do the exact same thing. The reason I have a `Language` Entity is because the Languages tab will be a combination of languages that have videos and leaflets.

So in the `Languages` tab, my `fetchedResultsController` is:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Language" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    fetchRequest.entity = entity;
//    NSPredicate *d = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name != nil"];
//    [fetchRequest setPredicate:d];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"videos.language" ascending:YES];


    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

And the `cellForRow` is:

```
VideoTabTableViewCell *customCell = (VideoTabTableViewCell *)cell;

Language *languages = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

customCell.videoTabCellLabel.text = languages.videos.language;
customCell.videoTabCellLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

**Update**
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"langauges tab";

```
    VideoTabTableViewCell *cell = (VideoTabTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id  sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.languagesTabTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    // The boiler plate code for the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

    UITableView *tableView = self.languagesTabTableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    [self.languagesTabTableView endUpdates];
}
```

I am calling the `fetchedResultsController` from `viewDidLoad` and reloading the table from `viewWillAppear`.

However, the situation on the `Languages` tab is that it only shows the last language that I added in, and every time I launch, I creates another new empty cell.

[image]

I just can't figure out what's actually going on with this.

The clarify, the main issue here isn't the phantom cells, but why the Language is only picking up the last entry and not the others.

Any guidance would really be appreciated.

Comment: A couple of comments: 1. I'm missing the dequeue at the cellforrowatindex... 2. is it possible the cells are empty because they're null 3. Are you missing data from NSFetchedResultsController or it's just not diplaying 4. Put some nslogs and check the above and also put some break points in relevant areas and do po <var>

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply @RoyFalk - I appreciate it. I wasn't fully showing the code for the cell (sorry about that) and the NSFRC as well. I've provided that in an update. I placed an NSLog in the cellForRow with languages.videos.language and the result is NULL, NULL and then Tamil. This class has the same code as the Videos tab, except with the NSFRC being different and the cellForRow pointing to languages.video.language instead of video.language..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to refine your data model:

First, the relationship from `Language` to `Video` has a plural name, `videos`, which suggests you want each `Language` object to be related to many `Video` objects.  But the image from the model editor shows that the relationship is currently defined as "to-one".

Second, why have a `Language` entity, *and* a `language` attribute on the `Video` entity?  From your code, it looks like the `language` attribute is a string representing the name of the language.  I would suggest you should instead have a `name` attribute on the `Language` entity.

In addition to those points, the crux of your problem is your `loadVideosTab` method.  It creates only one `Language` object:

```
Language *language = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Language" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

and then creates (or fetches) several `Video` objects, and establishes the relationship with the (one) `Language`, e.g.:

```
Video *chineseLanguage = (Video *)[Video videoLanguage:chinese inManagedObjectContext:context];
language.videos = chineseLanguage;
```

However, because the `videos` relationship is "to-one", the `Language` object can be related to only one `Video`.  So each time you set the relationship, the old one is removed.  At the end of your method, your one `Language` is related only to the Tamil `Video` object.  The other seven `Video` objects are not related to any `Language`.

Each run creates a new `Language`, and establishes a relationship to the Tamil `Video`.  Because each `Video` can have only one `Language`, when that relationship is made, CoreData drops the Tamil video's relationship to the "old" `Language` object.  Hence you end up with several "old" `Language` objects that are not related to any `Video` - these are the blank lines in your Language table view.

**EDIT**

A note on handling to-many relationships: the relationship is represented as an NSSet.  If you are setting a relationship (and want to remove existing relationships), you can use:

```
language.videos = [NSSet setWithObject:tamilLanguage];
```

Or to set multiple objects all at once, use:

```
language.videos = [NSSet setWithArray:@[chineseLanguage, dutchLanguage, tamilLanguage]];
```

These blow out existing relationships, so to *add* a relationship, whilst keeping the existing, use `NSMutableSet`:

```
NSMutableSet *videos = [language mutableSetValueForKey:@"videos"];
[videos addObject:tamilLanguage];
```

(and similarly for `removeObject` to remove just one of the related objects).  I find these methods rather unintuitive, so if I have a relationship whose inverse is "to-one", I use that instead:

tamilLanguage.videoLanguage = language;

Having said that, I'm now wondering whether that inverse relationship should also be "to-many" - can a `Video` have many `Language`s?

Comment: Dear @pbasdf, that's extremely helpful. I wasn't feeling too confident about the Core Data model and your message has pointed me in so many positive directions and I thank you for that. Each Language indeed can have one or multiple videos; if I set that in the model, the NSManagedObject subclass has <NSSet *> as it's requirement for the Videos Entity. How do I use that appropriately to add in the the data in the same or similar way in the loadVideosTab method? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the use of to-many creates @property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<Video *> *videos in the NSManagedObject Subclass for Language - but I'm not sure how to use the NSSet to create entries, because now, I'm getting an error on the Language tab cellForRow indicating that Language *whichLanguage; whichLanguage.videos.language doesn't exist (I haven't made the change to add "name" to the Language tab yet but I will)

Comment: With a bit of work, I managed to get this done but you pointed me in the right direction - thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with managed objects but this looks like it behaves like a dictionary.  Multiple insertNewObjectForEntityForName with the same name would mean that the last one overwrites the rest.

The Apple doc seems to indicate this too:

> Discussion
>     This method makes it easy for you to create instances of a given entity without worrying about the details of managed object creation. The method is conceptually similar to the following code example.

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel =
        [[context persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectModel];
NSEntityDescription *entity =
        [[managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:entityName];
NSManagedObject *newObject = [[NSManagedObject alloc]
            initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
return newObject;
```

**Note the above objectForKey! Same as NSDictionary**

=================================================================

dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier doesn't always return a non-nil object. It's used to reuse existing cells. But if there isn't one available, you need to alloc/init one.

Kudos to [Jay Versluis](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-dequeue-uitableviewcells-manually/)

Something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
  if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
  }

  // populate your cell
  return cell;
```

}

Comment: Hi @RoyFalk - many thanks for that and that is quite interesting. I'll be deploying that. I put a NSLog in the method that creates the Core Data items at the end of it and only "Tamil" comes up - why does it not register the rest of the languages but just the last one inserted, when Videos *video; video.language brings in all the data? Is it related to one-to-one or one-to-many relationships?

Comment: @amitsbajaj See my revised answer above.

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses, I appreciated it. Unfortunately, I had to refine my data model as per the other answer, but your code was really helpful, so while I can't accept it, I've upvoted it. Thanks again!